# Why no "each" method on Perl6 sequences?

Tags: raku

Sometimes I'll start writing a chain of method calls at the Perl 6 REPL, like:

```
".".IO.dir.grep(...).map(...).
```

...and then I realize that what I want to do with the final list is print every element on its own line.  I would expect sequences to have something like an `each` method so I could end the chain with `.each(*.say)`, but there's no method like that that I can find.  Instead I have to return to the beginning of the line and prepend `.say for`.  It feels like it breaks up the flow of my thoughts.

It's a minor annoyance, but it strikes me as such a glaring omission that I wonder if I'm missing some easy alternative.  The only ones I can think of are `».say` and `.join("\n").say`, but the former can operate on the elements out of order (if I understand correctly) and the latter constructs a single string which could be problematically large, depending on the input list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you wrote in the comment, just an other `.map(*.say)` does also create a line with True values when using REPL. You can try to call `.sink` method after the last map statement.

```
".".IO.dir.grep({$_.contains('e')}).map(*.uc).map(*.say).sink
```

Comment: I suppose...but then the REPL will spit out a list of `True` values of the same length as the input list.  Not ideal.

Comment: `".".IO.dir.grep(*.contains("e")).map(*.uc).map: {.say; Empty}` will do the same, but only mention an empty list in the REPL

Comment: I believe the REPL is meant to not output the result of a line if there has been output; it does that by calling `tell` on the out filehandle before and after the command and compares them, I think? so something might be going wrong with that logic.

Answer (score 11):

You can roll your own.

```
use MONKEY;

augment class Any 
{ 
    method each( &block )
    {
        for self -> $value { 
            &block( $value );
        }
    }
};

List.^compose;
Seq.^compose;

(1, 2).each({ .say });
(2, 3).map(* + 1).each({ .say });

# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4
```

If you like this, there's your *First CPAN module* opportunity right there.

Comment: Great answer and idea for a CPAN module.  You might consider mentiong it can be  made into a regular sub and called with `.&each()`, in case they don't want to fuddle with augmenting.

Comment: Using the `.&each()` format comes with downsides, such as being required to stick to a single line (or use rather unwieldy `\ ` all over the place).